# Can I use a variable as a key in Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basic Javascript/jQuery question: How can I use a nonliteral for the key in a key/value pair? I thought the following syntax (below) would parse, but it does not. I am trying to make a dialog that is dynamic. I want the button text to be variable. How can I do this with Javascript/jQuery?  Or do I have to invoke PHP on my .js file? (So don't want to do this...)

```
function see_menu_custom(t1, m1, t2, m2, t3, m3, t4, m4, t5, m5)
{   
    $(document).simpledialog2(
    { 
        mode: 'button',
        headerText: 'Send Message',
        headerClose: true,
        showModal: true,
        animate: false,
        buttons :
        {
            t1: /******** How can I make this a nonliteral? *********/
            {
                click: function () { 
                    sendMessage(username, token, t1, m1);
                },
                iconpos : "right",
                icon : "arrow-r",
                theme : "e"
            },
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bracket notation is the right answer, but as you seem to be asking how to pass it, too, construct like this

```
function see_menu_custom(t1, m1, t2, m2, t3, m3, t4, m4, t5, m5)
{   
    var myButtons = {};
    myButtons[t1] = {
        click: function () { 
            sendMessage(username, token, t1, m1);
        },
        iconpos : "right",
        icon : "arrow-r",
        theme : "e"
    };
    // rest of buttons
    ...
    // then pass into next step
    $(document).simpledialog2(
    { 
        mode: 'button',
        headerText: 'Send Message',
        headerClose: true,
        showModal: true,
        animate: false,
        buttons : myButtons, // here
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation).

```
buttons[var] = {};
```

Comment: How exactly would I use this in my code? Like this?
`... animate: false,
buttons[t1]: {
                click: function () { 
                    sendMessage(username, token, t1, m1);
                },
                iconpos : "right",
                icon : "arrow-r",
                theme : "e"
            }, buttons[t2]: ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can only use strings for object literals, to use an expression you must use square brackets and assignment:

```
buttons[expression] = value;
```

Comment: How would I do this in my example? The jQuery stuff is throwing me off.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you can't do that with literal object notation.

But, I think using the title as a key is a less natural representation compared with putting the buttons in an array:

```
function see_menu_custom(t1, m1, t2, m2, t3, m3, t4, m4, t5, m5)
{   
    $(document).simpledialog2(
    { 
        mode: 'button',
        ...
        buttons :
        [
            {
                label: 'My arbitrary string value',
                click: function () { 
                    sendMessage(username, token, t1, m1);
                },
                ...
                theme : "e"
            },
        ]
```